# Numpy array without for loop

Tags: python, numpy

```
array = np.empty(8,4)

for I in range(8):
   array[I] = I
```

Can this be implemented without for loop. I would like know other approaches

```
array = np.empty(8,4)
for I in range(8):
   array[I] = I 

[0,0,0,0]
[1,1,1,1]
    .
    .
    .
[7,7,7,7]
```

Comment: What are you trying to create with `np.empty(8,4)`?

Comment: creating 8 rows and 4 columns 2 dimensional array and assigns 0 for every cell.Syntax typo: np.empty((8,4))

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to just use `np.repeat`:

```
array = np.repeat(np.arange(8), 4).reshape(8, 4)

array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 7]])
```